# How to add :hover or :active to contents created using ::after or ::before

Tags: css

Is it possible to add :hover to ::after or ::before elements?

I've tried it in multiple ways but it's not working, is there another workaround for it.

Comment: "I've tried it in multiple ways" - could you just add a snippet of something you have tried? We could go from there to see what the problem is. Better yet, provide a code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coincidentally, I just used this snippet for the `hover::after` demo.

The button shadow is using `button::after`, but whenever a user hovers on that button (`button:hover::after`), the button shadow needs to be reset to position (0,0) for matching with the original button layer.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

button {
 position: relative;

  color: black;
  font-size: 1.625rem;

  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid white;

  padding: 15px 50px;

  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: translate(0.8rem, 0.8rem);
  color: white;
}
button:hover::after {
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

button::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0.8rem;
  top: 0.8rem;

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid white;

  transition: all 0.2s;

  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<button>
BUY 
</button>
```

If it's still not working for you, you need to check `content` attribute is used in pseudo styles or not. If it's not there, no pseudo styles will be applied.